# R: How do I remove the sub (error) label in partimat plot from klaR package

Tags: r, linear-discriminant

I am wanting to produce a klaR::partimat plot with as small margins as I can (so it shows up nicely in a quarto document.)  I have managed to play with the margins & font size to get it close to what I want, but can't figure out how to remove the main label on each subplot (or at least set its font size to something tiny.)

This is the code I am currently using and I have attached a picture showing what I want to remove. Thanks for your help!

```
require(klaR)
partimat(Species ~ ., data=iris, method="qda",mar=c(1,1,1,1),plot.control=list(cex=1,cex.axis=0.01,tcl=NA,mgp=c(0.2,0.1,0.1)),main="")
```

[image: partimat plot]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out via a comment in the help file that says plot parameters are passed to **drawparti**. For that function, it allows you to set print.err=0, which fixes it:

require(klaR)
partimat(Species ~ ., data=iris, method="qda",mar=c(1,1,1,1),plot.control=list(cex=1,cex.axis=0.01,tcl=NA,mgp=c(0.2,0.1,0.1)),main="",**print.err = 0**)

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).